# I'm using Unity and creating a text based game where your options directly affect the health and need assistance

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add a healthbar which is affected by the choices made and link the two  but am unable to do so. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, reconsider using the Unity engine, if your goal is a text-based game.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you that before you go any further with your game development process, you research a bit more about general OOP programming (no offense or anything, it will just make things waaay easier, trust me).

That being said, here's an example to steer you to the right direction:

You can create a script with a global variable called health and subtract it every time the player makes a decision that would "punish" them, here's an example of how that could work:

**PlayerManager.cs** (put this script on your player)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public float health = 100f;

    private void Update() {
        if (health < 0)
            Die();
    }

    private void Die () {
        //Fancy animations and text can be added on this method
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

And on your dialogue script, once they choose a wrong answer, then you can just decrease health on the proper player manager instance, like this:

**DialogueSystem.cs**

```
public PlayerManager playerManager;
public float damage = 10f;

private void Start() {
        //You can initialize other stuff here as well
        //This line is assuming you have the dialogue system script attach to your player as well
        playerManager = GetComponent<PlayerManager>();
}

private void Update () {
        //This is obviously going to change depending on how your system is built
        if (wrongChoice) {
            playerManager.health -= damage;
            wrongChoice = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: I seee. Thank you for your assistance. I did end up figuring it out. And I shall look up OOP then. :)